# jQuery Bootstrap dropdown form fails on submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, forms

I have a jQuery JSON-populated dropdown menu in a Bootstrap form. the jQuery script pulls the options from a PHP populated file. Here I have it as a var for ease of use.

The jQuery dropdown menu is populated and on a click it selects the option.

On submit it returns the error `Notice: Undefined index: dog in . . .`"

As well as the PDO error: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'dog' cannot be null in`

From the error it doesn't appear to be passing along the value.

The form works fine if I run hardcoded radio buttons in place of the jQuery dropdown.

```js
var json = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "boris"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "nixon"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "audie"
  }
]
let dropdown = $('#dog');
dropdown.empty();

$.each(json, function(key, dog) {
  dropdown.append($('<a class="dropdown-item"></a>')
.attr('value', dog.name).text(dog.name))
$(".dropdown-item").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".input-group").find("input").val($(this).text())
});

});
$("#dog").on("change", function(e) {
  var selectedOption = this.value;
  alert(selectedOption)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- dog dropdown --> 
<div class="container">
 <div class="form-group row">
  <div class="form-group">
        
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" id="dog">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

The jQuery:

```
let dropdown = $('#dog');
dropdown.empty();

$.each(json, function(key, dog) {
  dropdown.append($('<a class="dropdown-item"></a>')
.attr('value', dog.id).text(dog.name))
$(".dropdown-item").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".input- 
group").find("input").val($(this).text())
});

});
$("#dog").on("change", function(e) {
  var selectedOption = this.value;
  alert(selectedOption)
});
 });
```

The relevant part of the form;

```
<!-- dog dropdown -->   
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="form-group">

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" id="dog">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-actions mt-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Create</button>
    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" href="index.php">Back</a>
</div>
```

The  PHP SUBMIT and SQL INSERT

```
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO db.table

(firstname,lastname,farm,type,dog,date_s,lat,lng,note,mts) 
    values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q>execute(array($firstname,$lastname,$farm,$type,$dog,$date_s,$ 
lat,$lng,$note,$mts));
```

Comment: Where's the code that submits the form?

Comment: Add your text input a **name** attribute, heh?

Comment: @skobaljic Thanks. That got it.  I was looking at a codepen I'm using as a model and noticed the missing name. I was heading there -- really. An answer would get you some points -- if you care.

Comment: Nah, it's just a typo, you can delete... that answer would have no connection to the question, cheers